# Binary search gets stuck

Tags: python, binary-search

As a computer science student we were given an assignment to do binary search in python. I don't know what's wrong with my code everything seems just fine
when the searched item is in the middle everything works just fine but whenever I enter a different index position it gets stuck in the while loop.

```
def binary_search():
    ordered_list = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

    lower_bound = 0
    upper_bound = 10
    index = int((lower_bound + upper_bound) / 2)
    item_f = int(input("please enter the number you want to find (1-10): "))
    t = True
    while t:
        if ordered_list[index] == item_f:
            print(f"number {item_f} is found at index position {index}")
            t = False
        elif item_f > ordered_list[index]:
            lower_bound = index + 1
        elif item_f < ordered_list[index]:
            lower_bound = index - 1

    if t == False:
        print("number found")
    else:
        pass
    
binary_search()
```

Comment: You never recalculate `index`. Meaning you just keep checking the middle of the list. Also in the second elif you should be changing the upper bound instead.

Comment: This code will not run at all. It is illegally indented. And it has a syntax error in the first line.

Comment: So what about your code is it that you think makes it a binary search?

Comment: sorry i didn't realise this indentation mistake  im still new to stack overflow

Comment: So why do you think this is a binary search?

Comment: what do you mean? i tried to implement the algorithm in python.no offense :)

Comment: is it not supposed to recalculate index because its a global variable?? the value of index show be recalculated everytime while loop repeats

Comment: Ok, I see where you are going wrong. So, just because you write: `index = int((lower ...` doesn't mean that it will be re-calculated in the future.  That line means that `index` is calculated exactly once based on the values of upper and lower at that time. See the answer from @ChanduSiddi for how you need to recalculate `index` inside the `while` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added 1 line of code, please check it should working

```
def binary_search()
    ordered_list = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

    lower_bound = 0
    upper_bound = 10
    index = int((lower_bound + upper_bound) / 2)
    item_f = int(input("please enter the number you want to find (1-10): "))
    t = True
    while t:
        if ordered_list[index] == item_f:
            print(f"number {item_f} is found at index position {index}")
            t = False
        elif item_f > ordered_list[index]:
            lower_bound = index + 1
        elif item_f < ordered_list[index]:
            upper_bound = index - 1#Edit line
        index = int((lower_bound + upper_bound) / 2) #Added line 

    if t == False:
        print("number found")
    else:
        pass
    
binary_search()
```

Comment: @ahmetk5113 you have made a small mistake, you put lower_bound instead of upper_bound, I have edit it now. please check the line with '#Edit line' in the above code.

Comment: thanks for your help its actually funny that i havent realised this before :)

Comment: @chandysiddi thanks man your help is appreciated :)